# Why both Integer is not equal?

Tags: objective-c, c, int, compare

I am not getting why this is happening ?

```
int a = 012;        
int b = 12;

if (a == b) {
    NSLog(@"equal");
}else
    NSLog(@"not equal");
```

why it is printing not equal ?

Answer (score 4):

Okay. This is because the C int type interprets literals with leading zeros as octal.

To demonstrate this, adapt your example to the following:

```
int a = 012;
int b = 12;
if (a == b) {
    NSLog(@"%d does equal %d", a, b);
} else {
    NSLog(@"%d does NOT equal %d", a, b);
}
```

Outputs:

```
10 does NOT equal 12
```

That is because in octal (1 * 8 = 8) + 2  = 10

Further information can be found at:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_literal#Affixes

Answer (score 1):

Leading zeros indicate that the number is expressed in **octal**, or base 8; thus, 012 is converted into octal as `(1*8)+2 = 10.` Because of this reason the `if statement` returning `false`.

```
int a = 012;
int b = 12;

NSLog(@"%d", a);
NSLog(@"%d", b);

if (a == b) {
    NSLog(@"equal");
}else {
    NSLog(@"not equal");
}
```

**Output:** **not equal**.